# Axis lines=middle doesn't center axis in (0,0). Difference between axis lines and axis lines*

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

Whenever I want axis go through (0,0) `axis lines=middle` works fine. But

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[clip=false, axis lines = middle, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]  
          
        % CURVE
        \addplot [smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(1,4.8)(1.5,3)(3.5,2)(5,-4)(6,3)(7,4.5)};
        
        % Pin showing where's axis intersection
        \addplot [mark=x] coordinates {(1,0)} node [pin={[pin edge={black}]320:{$(1,0)$}}]{}; 

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I thought the difference between `axis lines` and `axis lines*` were just arrow heads. But in this example, `axis lines*=middle` get axis intersection at (0,0), so why `axis lines=middle` doesn't ?

Comment: Just add `xmin=0` to the options of the axis.

Comment: I can add an empty node at (0,0) too. That's how I've been able to reproduce my expected output, but that doesn't answer my question @anonymous

Comment: Not 100% sure here,  but: "The case `center` is a synonym for middle, both draw the line through the respective coordinate 0. **If this coordinate is not part of the axis limit, the lower axis limit is chosen instead.**" From the manual. So I guess the difference between the two is that in the `*` case the axis limits are extended beyond the data, which makes zero be within the axis limits. In the other, that doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean there, but I actually think the manual is clear: the y-axis line will *only* be placed at x=0 *if*  `xmin` is <= 0 and `xmax` is >0. That's the point of what I put in bold.  In your case `xmin` is always *larger than zero*, so the y-axis line is placed at `xmin`.

Comment: When I used `axis lines*=middle`, I didn´t specify `xmin`<= 0, but y-axis line was placed at x=0

Comment: No, it wasn't. It was placed at `xmin`, which was a little bit above zero. Add `xmin=0` and you'll see that.